# MongoDB java driver aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb

Given the following MongoDB query, I would like to implement it in Java not by using *Document.parse* , but by using Mongo Java Driver *aggregation classes*. I would be thankful if anyone could provide me a simple example in Java.

[image]

And the link for the following page :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/#pipe._S_bucket

Comment: Take a look [BucketOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/BucketOperation.html) please

Comment: You can use [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) to access and query the database using a Java application.